# AWS DB for private project, which one to use?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

Folks, I want to create a paid app and host it on AWS and the DB also on AWS, however I cant decide which DB to use since mySQL and Maria are both under GPL, which Engine can I use so that I dont have to share the code? My web app will run on a server and the mobile app locally but connected via webservice.

thanks

Comment: why would you have to share the code?

Comment: I assumed that under GPL once people download the app locally they have the right to have the source code, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you do not need to share the source code for your app, because it is not a derived product of a product under the GPL.

It may *use* a GPL product, presumably AWS RDS (or mysql or mariadb running on an instance).

But your product is not a derived product of any GPL that you have mentioned yet.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know that..

Comment: if that wasn't the case, only a handful of companies could get away without sharing all their code. Think about everything that flows out of the [Apache Software Foundation](http://www.apache.org/index.html#projects-list) and elsewhere